# Gitlab-ci runner hangs after cypress tests

Tags: gitlab-ci, cypress

I am using **gitlab-ci** to tests a react application with **cypress**.

The test seems to pass but it hangs after executing `cypress run` command.
Thus, the test fails because of the timeout.

My service is the following

```
cypress:
  image: cypress/base:10
  script:
    - serve -s build -l 3000 & yarn wait-on http://localhost:3000
    - yarn cypress:run
```

And in my package.json

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "cypress:run": "cypress run --spec 'cypress/integration/**/*spec.js' --record false --config video=false"
  },
  ...
}
```

This is the end of gitlab-ci runner's log:

```sh
    ✔  All specs passed!                        01:01       11       11        -        -        -  

Done in 73.82s.
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 20m0s seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

this issue occurs when a background task is running in the runner

To fix this I put in an or condition on the cypress:run step and kill the process if the result is not a success

there is another kill statement added in the step below also in case -parallel is used and multiple steps are running

Something like this

```
 script:
# start the server in the background
- npx serve -s build -p 3001 & 
# run Cypress tests in parallel
- yarn cypress:run || (ps -ef | grep [s]erve| awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 )
- (ps -ef | grep [s]erve| awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 ) || exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help someone, but it is worth to try updating node.

I had the same problem when using cypress 11.1.0 and `node:16.17.1-slim` docker image. I do not experience hang ups with `node:16.18.1-slim` anymore.

P.S. Along with node update I've updated Chrome from 106 to 107, so can't be sure what actually made the trick, just wanted to share with possible solution.